Reducing the size of a reaction scheme
I want to write the reaction balance of a reaction, specifying the names of the molecules below: for this part, no problem. In my document, I would like to reduce the whole but I don't know what is the best way to do it?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
%%Canizzaro
\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-@{atoc}C([6]=[@{db}]@{atoo1}O)-H)-=-)}}{Benzaldéhyde}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{OH^\ominus}}{}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
\chemname{\chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-C([1]-@{atoo2}\chemabove{O}{\scriptstyle\ominus})([6]=O))-=-)}}{Benzoate}
\+
\chemname{\chemfig{[:-30]*6((-C(-[5]H)(-[7]H)-[2]@{atoo1}O)-=-=-=)}}{Alcool benzylique}
\schemestop
\chemnameinit{}
\end{document}


Do you mean something like \chemfig{[:-30,0.5]*6(=-=(-@{atoc}C([6]=[@{db}]@{atoo1}O)-H)-=-)} (I've added 0.5 as a length multiplication coeffecient)

Change "atom sep" in \setchemfig
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    %%Canizzaro
    \setchemfig{atom sep=2.5em}
    \schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-@{atoc}C([6]=[@{db}]@{atoo1}O)-H)-=-)}}{Benzaldéhyde}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{OH^\ominus}}{}
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
    \chemname{\chemfig{[:-30]*6(=-=(-C([1]-@{atoo2}\chemabove{O}{\scriptstyle\ominus})([6]=O))-=-)}}{Benzoate}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{[:-30]*6((-C(-[5]H)(-[7]H)-[2]@{atoo1}O)-=-=-=)}}{Alcool benzylique}
    \schemestop
    \chemnameinit{}
\end{document}


